# laravel(5.5) there are no results in save method for a collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to save several rows after processing them but when checking any data was recorded in the db

my user table contains the code column with the format "yegftwr" and "BOL234", and I need to convert all the codes with the format "yegftwr" to "BOLxxx" where xxx is an incremental number

my code first gets all the codes and then looks for the highest number xxx separating the string "BOL"
(first loop)

then look for the first three characters of the "yegftwr" format codes, convert them to capital letters and compare them with the first three characters of "Bolivia" converted into capital letters
if they are different then the code "yegftwr" is converted into "BOLxxx" format, xxx is an incremental number
(second loop)

here my code:

```
  use App\User;
  use DB;

  public function handle()
{
    $tmp=User::select('codigo')->where('pais','Bolivia')->orderBy('codigo', 'asc')->get();
    $abc=strtoupper(substr('Bolivia', 0, 3));        
    foreach ($tmp as $cod)
    {
      if (strtoupper(substr($cod->codigo, 0, 3))==strtoupper(substr('Bolivia', 0, 3)))
      {
        $num=substr($cod->codigo, 3, 6);
      }
    }
      var_dump((int)$num);
      var_dump($abc.(string)(((int)$num)+1));
    foreach ($tmp as $cod)
    {
      if (strtoupper(substr($cod->codigo, 0, 3))!=strtoupper(substr('Bolivia', 0, 3)))
      {
        var_dump($cod->codigo);
        $num=(((int)$num)+1);
        $cod->codigo=$abc.(string)$num;
        $cod->save();
        var_dump($cod->codigo);
        var_dump("------------------------");
      }
    }

}
```

in the tests I did not get any error but no record is kept in the db

this is the output in the terminal after executing the script in the terminal

```
...
string(6) "ZtzBqO"
string(6) "BOL812"
string(24) "------------------------"
string(6) "zVuhyP"
string(6) "BOL813"
string(24) "------------------------"
...
```

but no data is stored in the db

Comment: Maybe you have declared a variable called `codigo` in your `User` model ?

Comment: Yes, if it is declared

Comment: Simply remove the declaration then. Laravel store the attributes in an array and declaring the variable in your model create a conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the user record you should add the '`id`' column to the `select()` method or remove the `select()` method.

`$tmp = User::select('id', 'codigo')->where('pais','Bolivia')->orderBy('codigo', 'asc')->get();`

or

```
$tmp=User::where('pais','Bolivia')->orderBy('codigo', 'asc')->get();
```

**Code:**

```
use App\User;
use DB;

public function handle()
{
    $users = User::select('id', 'codigo')->where('pais','Bolivia')->orderBy('codigo', 'asc')->get();
    $codePrefix = strtoupper(substr('Bolivia', 0, 3));        

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        if (strtoupper(substr($user->codigo, 0, 3)) == $codePrefix)
        {
            $lastCodeNumber = substr($user->codigo, 3, 6);
        }
    }

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        if (strtoupper(substr($user->codigo, 0, 3)) != $codePrefix)
        {
            $newCodeNumber = (((int)$lastCodeNumber)+1);
            $user->codigo  = $codePrefix.(string)$newCodeNumber;
            $user->save();
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: thank you very much, I work adding id to the select ♪♪ ヽ(ˇ∀ˇ )ゞ

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching data where 'pais' is 'Bolivia'. Result will display all data with Boliva. And in second foreach loop you are checking $cod->codigo is not equal to 'Bolivia'. Check your second if condition, is this should be equal to or not equal to

Comment: thanks for the answer but the condition is correct since it is being checked that if the first three capital characters of $ cod->codigo is different from the first three characters in capital letters of "Bolivia"

Comment: Your condition is checking if $cod->codigo is different than boliva then it should insert. But according to your Select query you will get only records with Boliva. So none of the record is inserting

Comment: there are 4 var_dump in your code so comment following code and post the output `var_dump((int)$num);
      var_dump($abc.(string)(((int)$num)+1));`

Comment: (ಠ_ಠ)   Are you trolling me? because that will not affect the code and you know it gggg

Comment: i just wanted to check what result you are getting from second foreach function

Comment: Well it's good to remove the echoes and everything remains the same, do not save anything in the db, there are no error messages  
   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If you are inserting a new record ,  where you have created a object ? To insert you have to create a object and for update you have to get object from record . Hope you know that

Comment: To which table you have to insert the data , create a model for that . . and create object here.

Comment: thank you very much for the answers and I will continue trying and the models and objects are already implemented add it to the question  ⊂(◉‿◉)つ